# Webpack: not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

The directory structure can be seen in the below screenshot

[image]

I am facing this problem -> webpack not found;
I have installed webpack as well as webpack-cli as devDepencies.
But still, I am facing this problem.

Comment: Did you run `npm install` first?

Comment: Yes, I did that.

Comment: Please add the full package.json file to your question, preferably not as image but by copy and pasting

Comment: Try removing the `node_modules` folder entirely and running `npm install` again

Comment: `{
  "name": "javascript-complete-guide",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "JavaScript - The Complete Guide",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "Maximilian Schwarzmueller",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.4.0",
    "webpack": "^4.40.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
  }
}
`

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I tried. It didn't work.

Comment: So I replaced `"build" : "webpack"` with `"build" : "node_modules/.bin/webpack"`  it didn't work.
But when I replaced it with `"build" : "node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"` It worked.
There seems some problem with the `Symbolic Links`. Is that a problem related to my system?